# Reading and Previewing Objects (PDF Files) and Uploading it to a Server

Tags: javascript, java, jquery, html, rest

I'm building a Webproject, where can list PDF-Objects [GET-Request], preview them and upload [POST-request] any PDF file into the server.

I'm encoding PDF Files into a base64 String but it can't be previewed. My idea is to create a List of PDFObjects where the base64 String is Stored with other Information like name etc. But as I said I cant get the PDF Previewed.
HTML Preview:

```
<iframe src="data:application/pdf;base64, "SlZCRV..... </iframe>
```

Base64 Encoding:

```
String base64CodeofPDF = java.util.Base64.getEncoder().encodeToString(fileContent)
```

Expected result:

[image: https://ibb.co/swnbLv9]

Answer (score 0):

I solved that previewving Problem with the `<embedded>` Tag

Solution looks like this:
`<embed type="application/pdf" src="data:application/pdf;base64, <TheBase64Code> "/>`

Any Tipps for Listing the PDF Files [There will be a GET-Method which will return a List (for example) ] (like the Picture above) after one click, the PDF File should be previewed.

Comment: Is there a better and elegant way to do that?